# Help create your first snap

Tags: snap

Has anyone managed to make the snap package from this site?

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/your-first-snap/

When I try I get the following errors:

```
From git://github.com/mikix/golang-static-http
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Please consider setting `go-importpath for the 'cam' part
env GOPATH=/home/c/.local/share/Trash/files/webcam-webui/parts/cam/go go get -t -d ./golang-static-http/...
/tmp/tmp26__r97x: 1: export: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin: bad variable name
Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmp26__r97x', 'env',
'GOPATH=/home/c/.local/share/Trash/files/webcam-webui/parts/cam/go',
'go', 'get', '-t', '-d', './golang-static-http/...']' returned non-
zero exit status 2
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add contents of `.yaml` file and full output and which command you did run to get that output?

Answer (score 2):

We have a [new getting started](http://snapcraft.io/create/) which may be more suitable, especially if you start working on snaps on 16.04 LTS desktop. People involved in the documentation will have a look at what's happening with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the getting started in the documentation at http://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/your-first-snap